# Adjective phrase/clause to describe the object of the sentence

Tags: phrases, adjectives, sentence, objects

Am I using the adjective phrase correctly in the following sentence? "I want to be someone like you, *smart and beautiful*."

I know that using the adjective phrase to describe the subject of the sentence would be correct as in "*Afraid*, John forced himself to run away from the cabin." So does the same apply to the object of the sentence as was the case in my first sentence?

Comment: Yes, but “be” is a copular (linking verb) which takes predicative complements, not objects. Although the _be_-clause has no overt subject, we understand it to be “I”, so any complements that may be present are subjective. I’d say there were two possible analyses of the subject complement(s): either there is just one complement, the NP _someone like you, smart and beautiful_, where the AdjP _smart and beautiful_ is modifying _someone like you_, **or** there are two separate complements: the NP _someone like you_ and the AdjP _smart and beautiful_.  I’m not sure which analysis is preferable.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence

> I want to be someone like you, smart and beautiful

is grammatically correct. But it would be much more natural (and simple) to insert the adjectives before the noun described:

> I want to be smart and beautiful, like you.

The simplest way of writing or speaking English is nearly always the best way.